# Send WSO2 Carbon logs to RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, elastic-stack

My organisation is using RabbitMQ and ELK to collect and analyst log information. we also use WSO2 API Manager (1.10.0) as gateway and need to send log of AM to RabbitMQ somehow. Could anyone please give some advices on how to achieve or show me where the related documents are available. I found a fabulous article for publishing WSO2 carbon logs to ELK, https://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2016/06/19/publish-wso2-carbon-logs-to-logstashelasticsearhkibana-elk-using-log4j-socketappender/, but cannot find how to send logs to RabbitMQ.

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no out of the box method to publish logs to RabbitMQ.

But wso2 carbon allows adding custom log appenders. So you can write your own log4j appender ([this](https://github.com/plant42/rabbitmq-log4j-appender) is an example for a Rabbitmq log appender). After that add it to the wso2 product's log4j properties. You can follow [this](http://heshans.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-add-log4j-appender-to-wso2.html) guide to write and add your own log4j appender to the wso2 product.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks heaps your advice. I will try this solution

Comment: I made a jar file which contains custom log appender. Where I need to put the jar file so log4j.properties can refer it? Thanks